# mogenerator: use of unresolved identifier

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, mogenerator

Trying to get coredata working with mogenerator. I have generated the human and machine files by adding an entry in the build phases:

```
/usr/local/bin/mogenerator --v2 --model virgin1/Model.xcdatamodeld -M virgin1/Model/GerneratedClasses/machine -H virgin1/Model/GerneratedClasses/human --swift
```

It generates (in my case) the Spot.swift and _Spot.swift files. So far  so good. But if I use the Spot class in the project like:

```
let result = Spot.importSpots(dict)
```

it gives me a "use of unresolved identifier 'Spot'"

Do I have to include the Spot class anywhere?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you add the classes to the project? Did you import anything?

Comment: the classes are shown in the project view, so I guess that they are 'added' to the project. no the Spot class is not imported anywhere. But I don't really know if I have to import that on a global place or just in the class I need it. Saw on an existing project that they are not explicid imported anywhere and the project is running. So i wonder, what I am doing wrong? (Sorry, I am new to that :-) )

Comment: Only ever import where you need, as a rule. Importing globally works but isn't good practice.